# Using JSON Object Name if Object name is a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using an API that returns an array of data, which I JSON.Parse in order to use the data. I am able to gather the proper data details, however I want to be able to link those details to the object which they are contained in.

I use the following code to gather my array and JSON parse:

```
var venue = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(venue);
```

which returns: `Object {4293315: Array[108]}`

I then parse through the array contained in '4293315' by running the following code:

```
for(var person in venue) {
    var personDetail = venue[person];

    for(detail in personDetail) {
        if(personDetail[detail].max_rssi > maxRssi) {
            venueDetails.push(personDetail[detail]);
        }
    }           
}

var capacity = venueDetails.length;
capacity --;
console.log("capacity: " + capacity);
var temp = JSON.stringify(venueDetails);
console.log(venue +": " + temp);
```

which returns:

```
capacity: 6
[object Object]: [{"mac_id":12960837,"wifi_uid":null,"first_seen":"2016-06-14T00:13:23.000Z","last_seen":"2016-06-14T00:13:23.000Z","max_rssi":-55,"latest_rssi":-55,"frames":1},...
```

The issue is that the object name is an id number, for example `4293315`, so I receive an error when I try to run `venue.4293315.name`.

Can someone please help me figure out how to store the object name so that I can associate the values contained inside with the object? For example, I want to be able to store the object name in a key and value map, so that I can later ask for the capacity information of each object or ID.

Comment: `venue['4293315'].name` ?

Comment: I won't always know the ID number which will be inside the brackets. So I guess my question is, how so I store that number to be used in a situation like that?

Comment: Could you explain why  'Object {4293315: Array[108]}' is a sensible output from the responds message -- looks like something could be broken before you get this far.

Comment: This is a 'GET' response from an external API, which I am parsing to contain in a JSON array. I can't change that response, so I am left working with what I have unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically get the value of the name by doing:

```
var objectNames = Object.keys(venue); // gives an array of the keys
```

Assuming you know there is only one:

```
var id = objectNames[0];
```

Then you can access the properties using `id` as others have shown.

Comment: This one worked for me. Thank you! Will this still work in the JSON object that gets returned contains many different elements?

Comment: Yes! It will give you all the top-level keys, regardless of how many there are or what their format is.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i use the  PropertyName with json Property, maybe help someone

```
        {
            "1": "English LL",
            "2": "Individuals and Societies",
            "3": "Sciences",
            "4": "Visual Arts # Music",
            "5": "Arabic LL",
            "Day": "Su"
          }
    //Change the number to 
           [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
            public string Day1{ get; set; }
           [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
            public string Day2{ get; set; }
           [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "3")]
            public string Day3{ get; set; }
           [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "4")]
            public string Day4{ get; set; }
           [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "5")]
            public string Day5{ get; set; }
           [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "6")]
            public string Day6{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `venue[4293315].name` to access the name of the venue.

If you really want to access the values using the format in the question, you can append a string "id" (or whatever you prefer) to the beginning of each id number. Then you can use `venue.id4293315.name`.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing numbers in objects, or if you need to get an item in an object based off of a variable, use bracket notation.

`object.property` is called Dot Notation and can be used, for the most part, if the property does not start with a number.

`object[property]` is called Bracket Notation and can be used to access a property that does not qualify as a regular variable name.

---

```
myObj = {
    'hello': 'world',
    '17921': 'foo'
}
```

In this example, you can access `myObj.hello` as normal, but you MUST use `myObj[17921]` to access the numbered name, which does not normally count as a valid JS variable name.

In the same right, if you have a variable called `numberId` that equals 17921, you can get the same number by using `myObj[numberId]`.

Comment: "regular variable name" --- I'd even call it "identifier" (as per the standard)

Comment: Thank you. So the question then becomes, how do I store ;17921' in the numberID variable to be used in that particular situation?

Comment: Are you asking about how to get the name of the property out of the JSON response? If so, a quick and rough idea... `for(var i in venue){ numberId = i; }`. After running that code, `numberId` would be whatever the number of the property's name is; assuming it is the only property.